Numerical integration over part of a sphere
I want to numerically compute the surface integral,
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1} d\theta \sin{\theta} f(\theta,\phi)
$$
Is there a clever transformation from this integral over part of the sphere, to an integral over the full sphere, so that I could use standard methods like Lebedev quadrature?
If not, what numerical methods would you recommend to solve this?

You can of course just extend the integrand by zero to the full sphere. The issue is that then you have an integrand that is not smooth, and you can't expect high-order convergence of quadrature formulas in that case.

why wouldn't a Gaussian quadrature of the appropriate order defined specifically for the given integration interval work? For things like Lebedev quadrature to work, the integrand must be a spherical polynomial, so such an integrand should be compatible with Gaussian quadratures on sub-intervals.

A simple Gauss-Legendre product rule might be worth exploring and, maybe, it’ll save you some headaches.

Do you assume the function $f(\theta,\phi)$ is periodic for $\phi \in [0,2\pi]$?

yes it is periodic in $\phi$
